# Accessing chemicalize.org via HTTP Service from API

Tags: java, linux

the below snippet of chemaxon  I was trying to run it on linux terminal, but I failed. Can anyone tell how can I run the following script from chemaxon (https://docs.chemaxon.com/display/marvinsketch/HTTP) in linux.Thanks.

```
HTTPServiceDescriptor descriptor = new HTTPServiceDescriptor();
descriptor.setURL("http://chemicalize.org/tomcat-files/datapage.jsp");

descriptor.addArgument(ServiceArgument.createArgument("mol", ""));
descriptor.addArgument(ServiceArgument.createArgument("special", ""));
descriptor.addArgument(ServiceArgument.createArgument("pka_width", 0));

Object result = null;
try {
    result = descriptor.getServiceHandler().callService(descriptor, "c1ccnccc1", "pka", 300);
} catch (ServiceException e) {
   System.err.println("Service call failed.");
}
System.out.println("Synchronized call returned: " + String.valueOf(result));


descriptor.getServiceHandler().callService(descriptor, new AsyncCallback<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String result) {
        System.out.println("Aynchronous call returned: " + result);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(ServiceException caught) {
        System.err.println("Asynchronous call failed.");
    }

}, "c1ccnccc1", "pka", 300);
```

Comment: "but I failed"  any error message or details? Also how did you run that?